# target_link_libraries and add_dependencies

Tags: cmake

Is there any use case in which

```
target_link_libraries(my-lib x y z)

add_dependencies(my-lib x) # this is not just a waste of bytes?
```

If so, can someone explain what it would be?

Comment: Is the "x" a directory having files of shared (SO file type), or standard (A file type) library? Or is the library file itself?

Comment: Are you using CMake version 2 or version 3?

Comment: This is a 10 year old question, and at the time Cmake 2.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In current CMake releases:

After some error checking `add_dependencies` results in a call to [`Target->AddUtility()`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/470c549c622ddddd0be3ae63945e40a1cad85923/Source/cmAddDependenciesCommand.cxx#L49). `x` is added to the list of [utilities](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/470c549c622ddddd0be3ae63945e40a1cad85923/Source/cmTarget.cxx#L509) for `my-lib`.

`target_link_libraries` does not result in a call to `AddUtility`, but it does add the arguments to the [`LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/470c549c622ddddd0be3ae63945e40a1cad85923/Source/cmTargetLinkLibrariesCommand.cxx#L424) target property.

Later, both the content of the `LINK_LIBRARIES` target property and the list of utilities are used to compute the dependencies of the target in [`cmComputeTargetDepends`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/470c549c622ddddd0be3ae63945e40a1cad85923/Source/cmComputeTargetDepends.cxx#L274).

The list of utilities in a target can not be queried at configure time, and is only used at generate time, so the use of `add_dependencies` with arguments which are libraries already added with `target_link_libraries` is redundant.

Comment: Could you please double-check all the links because all of them more or less redirects to the main GitLab page of CMake? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you're particularly interested in...

**From a conceptual point of view** -- I think you're right. It is a waste of bytes.

**From a CMake documentation point of view** -- You should prefer *make* so to guarantee the correct build order.

According to the documentation target_link_libraries, add_dependencies concepts was ideologically split.
Such an idea of split dependencies, and linker options is also persisted in the Makefile format in the GNU *make* tool.

[target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)

> ..Specify libraries or flags to use when linking a given target..

[add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html)

> ...Make a top-level <target> depend on other top-level targets to ensure
>   that they build before <target> does...

In modern CMake from 3.* you can **omit add_dependencies** if you will perform linking with an aliased target:

```
add_library(fooLib 1.cpp 2.cpp)
add_library(my::fooLib ALIAS fooLib)
...
target_link_libraries(fooBin my::fooLib)
```

Comment: You don't even need ALIAS - using library name is enough. "If a library name matches that of another target in the project a dependency will automatically be added in the build system to make sure the library being linked is up-to-date before the target links."[docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)
This should be enough:
`add_library(fooLib 1.cpp 2.cpp)`
`target_link_libraries(fooBin fooLib)`

Comment: @ololuki Wouldn't you like to correct the answer?

Comment: Regardless of if it's needed, you should use ALIAS targets anyways.

Answer (score -3):

It's used in cases where top-level targets depend on each other. That is, if *x* is a something that you add to your project (at top-level) with

```
add_library( x x.c y.c z.c )
```

you shall tell CMake about it. And you do that with *add_dependencies*.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the point of my question is whether **add_dependencies** is _redundant_ after **target_link_libraries**.

Comment: OK, I obviously got this a bit wrong. Anyway, I wouldn't have been able to comment in such depth as @seveire did, so thanks for that.