# When should I use CMake's add_dependencies instead of target_link_libraries?

Tags: cmake, dependency-management, target-link-libraries

I'm used to defining CMake target dependencies using the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command. Recently, though, I've noticed the existence of another command, [`add_dependencies()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html). When should I use the latter rather than the former?

Note: I tried reading this question: [target_link_libraries and add_dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27282938/1593077) - but the answers confused me. I understand I should not use *both*. But it's not entirely clear to me when I should use which.

Comment: Use `target_link_libraries` whenever you can. Otherwise use `add_dependencies`. It is simple.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: It's simple other than the fact that sometimes the targets are not link libraries, but ok.

Answer (score 1):

`add_dependencies` should only be used where you need to establish a dependency in the build process that would otherwise not be present.

If a you want to influence the linker options, you use `target_link_libraries`.

For `INTERFACE` targets `target_link_libraries` should be used, even if it doesn't have an effect on the linker options. An example would be "linking" a header only library: This usually only results in include directories being inherited; you use `target_link_libraries` for this nonetheless.

---

A notable example of using `add_dependencies` would be to make sure `MODULE` targets dynamically loaded by an executable target get built when building the executable.

Comment: `add_dependencies` is also useful for declaring a dependency on a custom target that drives custom commands for code generation

Comment: @AlexReinking I consider this scenario covered with "establish a dependency in the build process".

Comment: I was simply suggesting another "notable example"